# list=allpages does not deliver all pages

Tags: php, mediawiki

i have the problem, that i want to fill a list with the names of all pages in my wiki. My script:

```
$TitleList = [];
$nsList = [];

$nsURL= 'wiki/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&   siprop=namespaces|namespacealiases&format=json';
$nsJson = file_get_contents($nsURL);
$nsJsonD = json_decode($nsJson, true);
foreach ($nsJsonD['query']['namespaces'] as $ns)
{
  if ( $ns['id'] >= 0 )
    array_push ($nsList, $ns['id']);    
}

# populate the list of all pages in each namespace
foreach ($nsList as $n)
{
  $urlGET = 'wiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apnamespace='.$n.'&format=json';
  $json = file_get_contents($urlGET);
  $json_b = json_decode( $json ,true); 

  foreach  ($json_b['query']['allpages'] as $page)
  {    
    echo("\n".$page['title']);
    array_push($TitleList, $page["title"]);
  }
}
```

But there are still 35% pages missing, that i can visit on my wiki (testing with "random site"). Does anyone know, why this could happen?

Comment: trace this condition `if ( $ns['id'] >= 0 )`

Comment: the id's -2 (Media) and -1(Special) give back an error, when attached to `apnamespace=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki API doesn't return all results at once, but does so in batches. 
A default batch is only 10 pages; you can specify `aplimit` to change that (500 max for users, 5,000 max for bots).

To get the next batch, you need to specify the `continue=` parameter; in each batch, you will also get a `continue` property in the returned data, which you can use to ask for the next batch. To get all pages, you must loop as long as a continue element is present.

For example, on the English Wikipedia, this would be the first API call:

`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apnamespace=0&format=json&aplimit=500&continue=`

...and the `continue` object will be this:

`"continue":{
    "apcontinue":"\"Cigar\"_Daisey",
    "continue":"-||"
}`

(Updated according to comment by OP, with example code)

You would now want to flatten the `continue` array into url parameters, for example using `

See the more complete explanation here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Continuing_queries

A working version of your code should be (tested with Wikipedia with a slightly different code):

```
# populate the list of all pages in each namespace

  $baseUrl = 'wiki/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&apnamespace='.$n.'&format=json&limit=500&'; // Increase limit if you are using a bot, up to 5,000
foreach ($nsList as $n) {
  $next = '';
  while ( isset( $next ) ) {
    $urlGET = $baseUrl . $next;
    $json = file_get_contents($urlGET);
    $json_b = json_decode($json, true);
    foreach  ($json_b['query']['allpages'] as $page)
    {
      echo("\n".$page['title']);
      array_push($TitleList, $page["title"]);
    }

    if (isset($json_b['continue'])) {
      $next = http_build_query($json_b['continue']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. i get a "badcontinue" error when i make the next API-Call. so i just saved the parameter in a variable `$continue = result['continue']['apcontinue']`.  and in the next loop i add this variable to `&continue= $continue`, which results in the error "badcontinue". it neither works when i pass only `$continue = result['continue']`

Comment: So, what you need to do is flatten the returned "continue" element and add each of its key-pairs to the query URL. You can do it using something like this `http_build_query( $json_b['continue'] );`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your answers were a great help for me. It finally works! I'm very thankfully.

Comment: Glad to help :-)